# How to remove bullet point in front of a paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs, bullets

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sourabh Bajaj
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\Item}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{#2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{}{\Large XX}} & Email : \href{XX}{XX}\\
  \href{}{XX} & Mobile : X \\
\end{tabular*}

 \resumeItemListStart
 \Item
\makebox     
{3+ years of engineering experiences in multiple industries (petroleum, agrochemicals), and 2+ years of research experience. Adept in data interpretation, \& troubleshooting.}
\resumeItemListEnd

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Syngenta}{Chittagong, Bangladesh}
      {Senior Production Officer}{Feb 2019 - May 2019}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          { Performed documentation for standard audits (JSA , WRA, CRA,  PPE audits etc). Developed visual management in production line (ie Pictorial SOPs). Trained operation team on standard operating procedures. Implemented  product and process compliance and adherence to Syngenta CoP. Ensured work place safety and effective communication of Safety, Health and Environment to all team members.}
 \resumeItem{Projects}
          {Installation of Boshch Packaging Equipment}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {ZICOM Equipment Pte. Ltd.}{Dhaka, Bangladesh}
      {Process Engineer}{Jun 2012- Dec 2014}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          {Performed Heat and Material Balance. Reviewed  PFD and P\&ID to improve performance of facilities. Prepared  Standard Operational Procedure (SOP), HAZOP and HAZID. Commissioned process plant. troubleshooted process operation \& PLC-HM.}
        \resumeItem{Projects}
          {Condensate Fractionation Plant; Silicagel Dehydration Type Natural Gas Process Plant; Teg Type Natural Gas Process Plant }
      \resumeItemListEnd



  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------SKILLS-----------------




%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Auburn University}{Auburn, AL}
      {Doctor of Philosophy in Chemical Engineering}{Aug 2019 -- Present}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Yeungnam University}{Gyeongsan, South Korea}
      {Master of Science in Chemical Engineering}{Aug 2016 -- Feb 2018}

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%
%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
%\section{Programming Skills}
%  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
%    \item{
%      \textbf{Languages}{: Scala, Python, Javascript, C++, SQL, Java}
%      \hfill
%      \textbf{Technologies}{: AWS, Play, React, Kafka, GCE}
%    }
%  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bullet points do you want to remove, the open or the solid ones?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This section I want to remove the bullet =========================================================== " \resumeItemListStart
 \Item
\makebox     
{3+ years of engineering experiences in multiple industries (petroleum, agrochemicals), and 2+ years of research experience. Adept in data interpretation, \& troubleshooting.}
\resumeItemListEnd"

Comment: If it's just this bullet which you like to remove, you can place `\renewcommand\labelitemi{}` directly after `\resumeItemListStart`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the open markers with

```
\renewcommand\labelitemii{}
```

and the one in front of your subsections with

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{}
```

Note: the later one changes the indent. If you place it in the preamble it applies to all `itemize` lists of the corresponding level.

If you like just to remove the bullet in front of the first paragraph, place `\renewcommand\labelitemi{}` directly after `\resumeItemListStart` in this `itemize` environment.

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sourabh Bajaj
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\Item}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{#2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}


%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{}{\Large XX}} & Email : \href{XX}{XX}\\
  \href{}{XX} & Mobile : X \\
\end{tabular*}

 \resumeItemListStart
 \renewcommand\labelitemi{}
 \Item
\makebox     
{3+ years of engineering experiences in multiple industries (petroleum, agrochemicals), and 2+ years of research experience. Adept in data interpretation, \& troubleshooting.}
\resumeItemListEnd

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Syngenta}{Chittagong, Bangladesh}
      {Senior Production Officer}{Feb 2019 - May 2019}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          { Performed documentation for standard audits (JSA , WRA, CRA,  PPE audits etc). Developed visual management in production line (ie Pictorial SOPs). Trained operation team on standard operating procedures. Implemented  product and process compliance and adherence to Syngenta CoP. Ensured work place safety and effective communication of Safety, Health and Environment to all team members.}
 \resumeItem{Projects}
          {Installation of Boshch Packaging Equipment}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {ZICOM Equipment Pte. Ltd.}{Dhaka, Bangladesh}
      {Process Engineer}{Jun 2012- Dec 2014}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          {Performed Heat and Material Balance. Reviewed  PFD and P\&ID to improve performance of facilities. Prepared  Standard Operational Procedure (SOP), HAZOP and HAZID. Commissioned process plant. troubleshooted process operation \& PLC-HM.}
        \resumeItem{Projects}
          {Condensate Fractionation Plant; Silicagel Dehydration Type Natural Gas Process Plant; Teg Type Natural Gas Process Plant }
      \resumeItemListEnd



  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------SKILLS-----------------




%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Auburn University}{Auburn, AL}
      {Doctor of Philosophy in Chemical Engineering}{Aug 2019 -- Present}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Yeungnam University}{Gyeongsan, South Korea}
      {Master of Science in Chemical Engineering}{Aug 2016 -- Feb 2018}

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%
%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
%\section{Programming Skills}
%  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
%    \item{
%      \textbf{Languages}{: Scala, Python, Javascript, C++, SQL, Java}
%      \hfill
%      \textbf{Technologies}{: AWS, Play, React, Kafka, GCE}
%    }
%  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But Unfortunately, it is not working.  https://ibb.co/0MCjYmX

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Can I ask one more question under the same topic? How can I increase the margin of the same paragraph to full on both the left and right sides? And How can I enforce justified formatting for each paragraph?

Comment: For this you can have a look at the `leftmargin` key of the `enumitem` package and set it to `0pt`. But please ask a new question. In this way your question is more likely to be seen by others.